# the method getApplicationContext() is undefined

Tags: android

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


}
```

So this is what I have, and it shows an error and tells me The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MyLocationListener

what should I do to avoid this error

Comment: use a activity context instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: Is this method inside an `Activity`?

Comment: no it is not its a class that implements LocationListener

Comment: Then you need to pass a context to it

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you aren't in an `Activity` you need to pass a `Context` to the class. Wherever you instantiate this class pass your `Activities context`

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Then create a `constructor` in that class that accepts `Context` as a `param` and use that

```
public class MyClass {
    Context c;
    public MyClass(Context context) {
         c = context;
     }
}
```

then when you need to use it

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(c, "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

> `public class MyClass extends Activity`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ContentProvider try this

```
getContext()
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by extending Application class, my class is AppController:

```
public class AppController extends Application{
    ...
}
```