# getApplicationContext() error Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that allows a user to enter in a message and a phone number to which the message will be delivered. I am getting an error "cannot resolve method getApplicationContext()" I have looked at the answer here [the method getApplicationContext() is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678763/the-method-getapplicationcontext-is-undefined) but it didn't help me, maybe I am implementing it wrong but I am not sure! This code works fine as an activity but not as a fragment.

**FragmentTab1 class**

```
package com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentTab3 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtphoneNo = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}



    Button sendBtn;
    EditText txtphoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;



    protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");

        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS failed, please try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The method getApplicationContext() does not exist in the class `Fragment`. It does exist, however, in the class `Activity`, so you can use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to get the context from within a fragment object. (Assuming the fragment is attached to an activity so `getActivity()` will return a non-null object, which is usually true)

Answer (score 6):

Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Application context available in the Fragment Activity

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

You shouldn't use the `getActivity()` as context here because `Toast` can live longer than the activity that showed it (Home button as been pressed, another activity has been launched, etc.)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#Basics

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's enough with getActivity() as Activity extends Context.

Anyway, please consider whether you need a [Context with the lifecycle separated from you Activity's Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext()) to know if you need to use getActivity().getApplicationContext() or just getActivity().

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122627/should-i-use-getapplicationcontext-or-activity-this-in-a-long-running-asynctask) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create on non activity class a constructor that takes a context on argument, and on your activity class, you have to pass the context on declaration of object, like this:

```
//ON non activity class :
public class longcomputingtask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

    private  Context context ;

    public longcomputingtask()
    {
    }

    public longcomputingtask(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
    }

//   on activity class :

public Context context;
context=getApplication().getBaseContext();

longcomputingtask calcul =new longcomputingtask(context):
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: [using context in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-fragment).

Just call `getActivity()`, make sure it's not null, and call `getApplicationContext()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext()` did not exist or you can say not defined in the Fragment class that means you cannot access it inside Fragment class directly.

**So solution is that** instead of doing like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

you should use the `getActivity()` method like following

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

i hope it helps.