# How do I succeed in declaring variables globally, issue with context

Tags: android, android-context

I'm following tutorials on how to put functions that are used frequently in activities all in one place.

For example, a `toast` message that comes up throughout my project, instead of having the function in each and every activity, just having it called in one place, `GlobalFunctions.java`.

So, I get it with simple functions, for example, in `GlobalFunctions.java` :

```
public class GlobalFunctions {

    public void simpleMessage() {
        System.out.println("simpleMessage text goes here");
    }

}
```

And the I call it like this from `Activity1`:

```
GlobalFunctions simplemessage = new GlobalFunctions();
simplemessage.simpleMessage();
```

But what about? :

```
public class GlobalFunctions {

    public void simpleMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "simpleMessage text goes here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I've looked at several posts including [getApplicationContext() error Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562595/getapplicationcontext-error-android) and no matter what I put in the `Context` part of `Toast` I get a `Cannot resolve method` message. Also if there's any good tutorials for Dummies on this subject I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is [**`static`**](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) .

Static values allow you to use static `methods` `variables` ..etc in whole project.

You can use following concept:

```
public static class GlobalFunctions {

public static void simpleMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

And you have to invoke it like:

```
GlobalFunctions.simpleMessage(/*YourActivity.this*/ /*or*/ /*getActivity()*/, "toast");
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to pass the `Context` as a parameter from the `Activity` or `Fragment`.

And instead of instantiating `GlobalFunctions`, writing and using static methods can be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Java Utils class:

```
   public class Utils {

        public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
              Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    // for example on the Activity code

        Utils.showToast(this, "This is the toast text");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this Create class like this to pass  `Context` and `Toast` message as parameter like this

```
public class GlobalFunctions {      

    public static void simpleMessage(Context context,String message) {
        Toast.makeText(Context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

call this function like this

```
  GlobalFunctions.simpleMessage(YourActivity.this,"your Mesaage");
```

Comment: `GlobalFunctions.simpleMessage(YourActivity.this,"your Mesaage");` wont work because that's not static class also method, you have to extract it from variable.

Comment: @Ibrahim i was just updating my ans

Comment: I would prefer to keep your old answer, because it was carring different concept which more useful to whole question, now you edited it like all answers in the question which carrieng same concept and way so it's became some useless before.

Comment: @Ibrahim didn't get u my friend

Answer (score 1):

Keeping context in field beyond activity can be reason of memory leak, but there is some workaround.

You can create Singleton with application or application context and initialize it in `onCreate` in your custom application class. But you have to remember that you can't use this context to build views - it is not stylized.

Other way is just pass context as argument.

Sorry for missing code, response from phone :)